# How to add the prerequisite package to be installed with RPM installation while packaging the RPM

Tags: centos, rpm, packing

I am creating a RPM package(ex test.RPM) which has a dependency of nss tools.
because my test.RPM application adds CA certificate to Chromum\firefox browsers to trust my self signed certificate.So i added

```
yum install nss-tools in the %prep section of the spec file.
```

while installing the test.RPM(yum install test.rpm) it throws an error

> ```
> Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
>   The other application is: yum
> ```

I know the reason, yum is already locked by test package.

Could anyone suggest how to add the prerequisite package to be installed  with RPM installation while packaging the RPM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Requires: nss-tool
```

For more info see http://ftp.rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/dependencies.html